# validating uniqueness of field against other fields inside a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this validation

```
validates :second_name, uniqueness: { scope: :school_id }
```

it performs validation so there can be no students in the same school sharing the same second name. but what if i don't want user in certain school who have third_name same as somebody elses second_name? Is there a default option or do i need to write a custom validation mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently struggled with this and the solution was very simple:

```
validates [:second_name, :third_name], uniqueness: { scope: :school_id }
```

Unlike the array params on the `scope` that represents a combination, an array of here is either the `:second_name` or `:third_name` data unique to the `:school_id`.